# accessing AWS EC2 hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to connect to EC2 instance on the basis of hostname. Can anyone please help me in how I can connect to EC2 instance on the basis of hostname from outside AWS domain?

Right now I am using IP address to connec to EC2 instance.

All the help is highly appreciated.

Comment: By hostname, do you mean public dns name? Is your instance inside a VPC?

Comment: That should be available on your AWS dashboard.

Comment: Yes its under VPC. Do I need to create public DNS for this or there is any other way as well

Answer (score 0):

If your EC2 instance is inside a VPC and it doesn't have a public DNS name, you probably need to enable DNS Hostnames for your VPC. In the AWS Console, go to the VPC screen under "Your VPCs". Select your VPC, click the Actions button and select "Edit DNS Hostnames". Also make sure that DNS Resolution is enabled.

Note from the [AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html):

> If you enable DNS hostnames and DNS support in a VPC that didn't
>   previously support them, an instance that you already launched into
>   that VPC gets a public DNS hostname if it has a public IP address or
>   an Elastic IP address.